# iFrame scrollbar handing using JavasciptExecutor in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application, there is an iFrame which have some list of items but
only first 10 items will be loaded and visible to user at first shot. Upon
user scrolls the scrollbar, the next 10 items will be loaded in the scroll
pane.

I need to click on 11th item which can be loaded only when I scroll
down. But I am not able to scroll down using iFrame - scrollbar as this is
not identifiable using Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: Switch to iFrame and then try to scroll down.

Comment: It's not working ... I have already been tried but i failed

Comment: have a look on this link. It may help you http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/scrolling-web-page-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: Can you please provide your code you tried so far.

Comment: What did you try? Switch to iFrame by using iFrame ID